# Please assist with case when statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, case-when, case-statement

I would like to get some assistance with creating case when statement in my query.

I have following query which i am trying to modify

```
CASE    WHEN Hotelexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121)  and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121) 
                and engagementexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121) and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121)
                and travelexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121) and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121)
        THEN 'Yes'
        else 'NO' 
End As combinedflag
```

I would like to add **additional condition** for lets say hotelexpenses, when hoteexpenses > $100.00 , for engagementexpenses >100.00 and travelexpenses > 100.00 and if any of the above conditions have met in addition to my case statement then the flag should be 'YES' or else 'No' end as ABC

Now in the scenarios like the conditions only meet the hotelexpenses but not the other two then the flag should be yes if hotelexpenses>100.00 and remaining two are <100.00 . (Makes sense?) but if all 3 matches date criteria and does not meet amount then the flag should be No.

So my main questions is how can i use case when statement with 'and' & 'Or' in statement . Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You incorporate and/or logic into a case statement the same way you do it in a where clause.  In fact, the code you posted has some and logic.

Comment: You can add the two dates used in the case to variables, so you dont have to calculate every time and the case will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this :-

```
CASE    WHEN Hotelexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121)  and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121) 
                and engagementexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121) and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121)
                and travelexpenses between CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(),121) and convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(mm,6,getdate()),121)
                and (hotelexpenses > 100 OR engagementexpenses > 100 OR travelexpenses > 100) 
        THEN 'Yes'
        else 'NO' 
End As combinedflag
```

Comment: Hi Mihir, Below is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Field1      Field2     Field3        
Hoteexpeses      11-30-15    100%
TravelExpenses     12-25-15    100%
Engagementexpenses    06-30-16    100%
Description:
Field 1 - Types of expenses ,Field 2 - Expenses date ,Field 3 - Expenses in % 

If any of the field 1 condition meet the condtion field2(between todays date to 6 months) and meets field 3 (Greater then 100%) Yes 
If field1 does not meet the condition for field 2 or field 3 but field 1(travel expenses) does then the flag should be yes as long as the date is 6 months from todays date and the percentage is greater then 100%

Comment: need some sample data